# How can I enable variable highlighting and bracket highlighting for TextMate?

Tags: notepad++, textmate

I am trying TextMate on a Mac and there are a lot of things i miss on Notepad++ that I wish TextMate has. Does anyone know if there is a way to enable bracket highlighting so I can see which parantheses/bracket corresponds to which and variable highlighting so I can double click a variable and see all instances of that variable highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are ways to do any of the things you ask in TextMate. Check [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731790/are-these-notepad-features-available-in-textmate/4780346#4780346) to a sort-of-similar question.

From what I gather, NP++ seems to sit between TextMate and a full-fledged IDE feature-wise. If you are still looking for a powerful text editor on the Mac may I suggest you try [Komodo Edit](https://www.activestate.com/products/komodo-edit/) (cross-platform, more IDE-like than TextMate, has both features, easy to learn) or [Vim](https://www.vim.org/)/[Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) (cross-platform, super powerful, blow NP++ and TM in every department except ease of use and user-friendlyness).

Maybe you can check out [Coda](https://www.panic.com/coda/) and [Espresso](https://espressoapp.com/) or [Sublime Text 2](https://www.sublimetext.com/blog/articles/sublime-text-2-public-alpha) as well.

My favorite is Vim, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Install the TextFX plugin for notepad++.
Earlier it used to be bundled in notepad itself.But now all plugins are add-ons.
You will get all the stuff you want.

Answer (score 0):

Textmate should light up the opening bracket when your cursor moves past its corresponding closing bracket, but a lot of it depends on the language you're using and how well put together the bundle is for it.

You may also check out [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/); if you can suffer along with a Java-based IDE, it does what you ask for and more.  If you're doing web-based work, I highly recommend Espresso, as @romainl was nice enough to link to.